# Tensorflow/Numpy: How can I fix this error, so that I would get 2 target predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a CSV file with 2 columns of data. I built a regression approach model to make predictions. But currently, I can only get 1 prediction, what can I do to get 2 predictions. I previously used the following model

```py
def build_model():
  model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])
```

But I found a new model, so I used that one as shown below.

This is how I'm loading the data

```
column_names = ['longitude', 'Latitude']
raw_dataset = pd.read_csv('loglat.csv', names=column_names)

train_dataset = dataset.sample(random_state=0)
test_dataset = dataset.drop(train_dataset.index)
train_stats = train_dataset.describe()
train_stats = train_stats.transpose()
train_stats

train_labels = train_dataset.pop('longitude')
test_labels = test_dataset.pop('longitude')

normed_train_data = train_dataset
normed_test_data = test_dataset
```

### The new model

```py
from tf.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tf.keras.models import Model


def build_model():
    X = Input(shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())])
    hidden_1 = Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu)(X)
    hidden_2 = Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu)(hidden_1)
    out_1 = Dense(1)(hidden_2)
    out_2 = Dense(1)(hidden_2)

    model = Model(inputs=[X], outputs=[out_1, out_2])
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                  optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
    return model

model = build_model()

linreg = model.fit(normed_train_data, train_labels, epochs=1000, verbose=0)

test_predictions = model.predict(normed_test_data).flatten()
```

The error with this is:

> ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[130.4998]])]...

Comment: format the code and the error message properly so that the others can understand the problem more clearly

Comment: The problem is that your model has two targets ([out_1 and out_2]) but when fitting your data (i.e. `model.fit`) you are only passing one set of targets. But there should be two targets as your model expects two targets. So you should be calling this function like `model.fit(normed_traindata, [train_target_1, train_target_2])`.

Comment: On a side note, change the line `model = Model(inputs=[X], outputs=[out_1, out_2])` to `model = Model(inputs=X, outputs=[out_1, out_2])` as well. I don't see the value of having `[X]` when you can simply have `X`.

Comment: thush89 what should I used as my train_target_2?